# How do I code excel with a static cell value and that is used in a formula

Tags: c#, excel-interop

```
memsheet.Cells[2,6] = Ram;

   excel.Range Consumed;
   consumed = memSheet.get_range("D2", "D5");
   consumed.Formula = "(F2 - C2)";
```

If I do this then the first value in Column D2 is correct, but the rest is incorrect,
when I open excel and check the formula it gives me =(F3-C3) so on for the range. This is not what I want the formula should be =(F2-C3) the C3 is what will be changing the whole time until the end of the column, but I don't know why this doesn't work :(

Comment: Totally out of context but try EpPlus http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680421/Create-Read-Edit-Advance-Excel-2007-2010-Report-in

Comment: Try: `consumed.Formula = "($F$2 - $C$2)";`